# MultiTenant application in MeteorJs

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working on a MultiTenant application in MeteorJs and using account-base package to create and manage user accounts.
I have got around the issue of unique userid by concatening the domain with the email. I am however getting an error when registering the same emailid for different domains.
What is the communities recommendation for account registration and all the functionality that the Accounts-UI, accounts-base package provides?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're asking if you can have multiple apps connected to the same "users" collection and have different logins? If so, then you can't.

Within the same mongo "users" collection, you should only have unique email addresses. While it's not enforced with an index, it does mess up the password reset. I.e, when you do a password reset request and enter the email address, how does it know which account to do the password reset on?